# Copy a File as a Different AD Group User in Python

Tags: python, active-directory

I'm trying to create a tool in Python that will pull archived XMLs for non-developers. Here are some of the givens:

- We are in different Active Directory Groups (e.g. Developer, and Analyst)
- Files are stored on multiple remove servers (e.g. Dev, QA, PROD)
- I have access to all of these, they do not (and it looks like the business will not allow that to change)

What I'd like to do is have Python copy the XML files as me. Is there a way to do that? Something where the call to copy a file would pass my credentials instead of theirs?

Thanks.

Comment: When you run your script all operations will do from AD account with which you login in domain.

Comment: So there's no way to get around that? I was hoping there was a way to wrap it in a request that looks like it's originating from another user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be an administrator (more accurately, have the privilege to impersonate another user).  Then you can execute an application under a different domain user like this:

```
handle = win32security.LogonUser('analystuser', 'mydomainname', 'password', win32con.LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, win32con.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT)
win32process.CreateProcessAsUser(handle, None, 'myapp.exe', None, None, 0, 0, None, None, win32process.STARTUPINFO())
```

However, you probably do not have that privilege and that's the end of the story.

Comment: When you say you need to be an admin, are you refering to on your own computer or an admin of active directory?

Comment: @aosmith - If you want to impersonate an AD user, you need corresponding rights in the AD.  See here fore more info: http://serverfault.com/questions/185813/which-ad-permission-is-required-to-allow-impersonation-of-an-account